# Import com.facebook.android.R; not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

Hi there I am trying to impor the facebook sdk project into Eclipse EE Kepler but I always get this stupid error about the import that doesn't found..

import com.facebook.android.R;

I already deleted project and add it again.. 
I already comment the classes with errors to see if the file would be generated..
I already restarted eclipse..
I already right-clicked the project and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties
I already clean the problem..

Any thoughs on how to fix this?
Thanks alot in advance..

Comment: try `cntrl + shift + o`

Comment: are you getting this error in the FacebookSDK or your project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use ctrl + shift + o , it uses import android.R; instead and where is not my string values..

Comment: I am getting this error on facebook sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't had the Android SDK Build-tools installed on my eclipse, installing the last version solved the problem. The Gen files are now generated :)

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @ DarkLink i have some problem pls tell me how to get rid from this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with any of your .xml file's error. Just check your `res/layout` folder. It must be showing error. Open that appropriate .xml file that shows the error. May be your missing some of your resources. Try to solve that error and then clean the project and it's done.

Comment: I already checked each xml file inside the layout folder and all of them are okay, didn't pop up any error inside the xml markup